# SQL ON DELETE CASCADE, Which Way Does the Deletion Occur?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, cascade, relation

If I have two relations in a database, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses (
  CourseID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Course VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Code CHAR(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE BookCourses (
  EntryID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  BookID int NOT NULL,
  Course CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  CourseNum CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  CourseSec CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

and I establish a foreign key relationship between the two, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE BookCourses
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Course)
REFERENCES Courses(Code)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then you can see that the `Course` attribute in the `BookCourses` relation references the `Code` attribute in the `Courses` relation.

My question is when a deletion occurs in either of the two relations, which way does the deletion cascade? If I delete a tuple in the `Courses` relation, will it delete all referencing tuples in the `BookCourses` relation, or is it the other way around?

Comment: One only wonders why the `Categories` table has a `CourseID` as the Primary Key while the `Courses` table has the `EntryID`. You seriously need to rethink your naming choices.

Comment: Please user proper column names to avoid confusion and clear DB structure.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Cascade will work when you delete something on table `Courses`. Any record on table `BookCourses` that has reference to table `Courses` will be deleted automatically.

But when you try to delete on table `BookCourses` only the table itself is affected and not on the `Courses`

*follow-up question: why do you have `CourseID` on table Category?*

Maybe you should restructure your schema into this,

```
CREATE TABLE Categories 
(
  Code CHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CategoryName VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Courses 
(
  CourseID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  BookID INT NOT NULL,
  CatCode CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  CourseNum CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  CourseSec CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE Courses
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CatCode)
REFERENCES Categories(Code)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: This answer has different table names and structures than the question... Making it far less useful.

Comment: @DanielBeardsley, I do not agree that this answer is not useful. That is if you read what it says. I do, however agree that the answer could be formatted so it’s clear what is part of the actual answer and what is another discussion. The schema highlighted above is related to the _follow-up question_ but not the answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 36):

Here is a simple example for others visiting this old post, but is confused by the example in the question and the other answer:

*Delivery -> Package (One -> Many)*

```
CREATE TABLE Delivery(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    NoteNumber NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Package(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Status INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Delivery_Id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Package_Delivery_Id FOREIGN KEY (Delivery_Id) REFERENCES Delivery (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

The entry with the foreign key Delivery_Id (Package) is deleted with the referenced entity in the FK relationship (Delivery).

So when a Delivery is deleted the Packages referencing it will also be deleted. If a Package is deleted nothing happens to any deliveries.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember: **Relational databases are all about consistency**. They want to ensure the data is consistent all the time.

[image]

If you have an `Author` table and a `Book` table, the `Book` table might have an `author_id`. Assume the `author_id` is set to `on_delete=CASCADE`.

The DB will become active when an author is deleted. When an author is deleted, the Book table could reference an ID that does no longer exist. Meaning that a deletion of an Author might need a "cascading" deletion of a book.

There are several possible types of values, but the most important are:

- CASCADE: If an author is deleted, delete all the books of the author.
- PROTECT: If you attempt to delete an author who has still books, let the deletion request fail. You need to explicitly delete the books first.
- SET_NULL: If an author is deleted, set all books the author_id NULL