# Unable to delete a row from a table due to a dependency/reference in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that deletes a record from a table where one of the columns matches a specified value:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_DelBranch] @datafield varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Branch WHERE branchname = @datafield     
END
```

Unfortunately I get the following error on execution:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_BranchIdDept". The       conflict occurred in database "MproWorkSpace", table "dbo.Department", column 'BranchId'.

Can anyone explain why I'm seeing this error?

Comment: Great, I'd say it works

Comment: The error occurs in your stored procedure. Please add that code.

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_BranchIdDept".

The record you're trying to delete is referenced in other tables; deleting the Branch record would leave the other tables orphaned, and referencing something that no longer exists.

There are two approaches to this:

1. Delete all records in referenced tables before deleting from the Branch table
2. Perform a [cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete) (deleting from the Branch table triggers a delete in every referenced table)

Comment: You got me right. Very well explained the solution. Thanks a lot .

Comment: How to  see all the constraints which I made earlier ?. I didn't care about naming them but now I want to apply the cascade delete on all of them .  Whenever error comes only then I get to know about their name.

Comment: In `SQL Server Management Studio`, in the `Object Explorer`, right-click the table `dbo.Branch` and select `View Dependencies`. The default view `Objects that depend on [Branch]` will show all tables, stored procedures, etc. that depend on the Branch table.

Answer (score 1):

> conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_BranchIdDept".

This means, that the `value` you are trying to delete, is `primary key` in some other table and is referenced in this table as `foreign key`,i.e., a primary-foreign key relation is mapped through constraint `fk_BranchIdDept` ...So unless you delete the referred primary key, foreign key can not be removed from table.

Otherwise, this will lead to data inconsistency!

Look for `Cascade Delete` to help you in this!

[SQL ON DELETE CASCADE, Which Way Does the Deletion Occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444859/sql-on-delete-cascade-which-way-does-the-deletion-occur)

Comment: How do you delete the PK, without deleting the FK? I think you got it the other way round

Comment: The structure is like - WorldBank is a group and WorldBank Italy is the branch. The branch has its dependency on WorldBank. I just want to delete the branch in italy .

Comment: The table of branches is having the field GroupID as the FK.

Comment: this community sure is awesome in terms of answering...glad we could help!! :D

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there are some rows in `Department` table referencing the branch you're trying to delete.

You should either delete the corresponding rows from the `Department` table first, or change values in `BranchId` column for these rows, so they point to some other branch.