# MVC Delete record with multiple required foreign key restraint

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

Deleting from a join-payload table in MVC, is no fun at all. Similar questions are related to a single foreign key and my situation is unique enough that I warranted it a question for itself (if not, please point me to a reference)

I've got this model (which acts as my joint table with payload - it acts as a join table between ApplicationUser and Car which are both data models)

```
public class UserHasCar
{
    // Foreign keys
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CarId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    // Additional fields
    public int YearsDriven { get; set; }

}

public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserHasCar> UserHasCars { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserHasCar> UserHasCars { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem exists when I am trying to delete a record (delete a UserHasCar entity from the database). Because a UserHasCar has two foreign keys, after running this code I get the following error:

```
List<UserHasCar> list = (from t in context.UserHasCars where t.ApplicationUserId == userId select t).ToList();

        foreach (UserHasCar car in list)
        {
            context.UserHasCar.Remove(car); // BOOM!
        }
```

The nasty error is: `A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion.`

My table definition looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserHasCars] (
[ApplicationUserId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[CarId]           INT            NOT NULL,
[YearsDriven]  INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserHasCars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationUserId] ASC, [CarId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserHasCars_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserHasCars_dbo.Cars_CarId] FOREIGN KEY ([CarId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cars] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Do I have to do something simple like EntityState.Deleted/Modified to my two foreign keys? I know its complaining about my clustered primary key and how I cannot delete it without removing the references to my foreign keys... I'm sure I'm missing something small here.

---

**EDIT**

As I'm looking through more closely, this line `List<UserHasCar> list = (from t in context.UserHasCars where t.ApplicationUserId == userId select t).ToList();` isn't pulling in the right ApplicationUser or Car from my database table, all values are null. I can see that the query isn't pulling in the proper ApplicationUser or Car, but why?

Comment: Are there any other tables, that use this table `UserHasCars` for a Foreign Key constrain on column [ApplicationUserId] with `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: @Stoleg No, but I stumbled across the fix to this problem. I will mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Car and User id were being set to default values, and didn't represent actual rows in the table. I've written about how I've solved it on this page (near the bottom):

http://programmerscheatbook.blogspot.com/2014/08/mvc-making-join-table-with-payload.html

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

string userId = [USER ID];
int carId = [CAR ID];

List <UserHasCar> list = (from rec in db.UserHasCars
                      join car in db.Cars on rec.CarId equals car.Id
                      where rec.ApplicationUserId == userId && rec.CarId == carId
                      select rec).ToList();

foreach (UserHasCar car in list)
{
    db.UserHasCars.Remove(car);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key data is being sent to the model?

If you are working with Entity Framework test:

Modelo.Remove (data) 
Modelo.SaveChanges ();

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing it from the main entities? For example

```
var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.userId == userId);

foreach(var car in user.Cars) {
    user.Cars.Remove(car);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to amend the deletion/cascading rules on your database regarding key dependencies.
[SQL ON DELETE CASCADE, Which Way Does the Deletion Occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444859/sql-on-delete-cascade-which-way-does-the-deletion-occur)

Be sure to read up first though and be aware of exactly what you are doing:

[When/Why to use Cascading in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297/when-why-to-use-cascading-in-sql-server)

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
{
    EmployeeContacts employeecontect = db.EmployeeContacts.Find(id);
    if(employeecontect!=null)
    { 
        db.EmployeeContacts.Remove(employeecontect);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    Employee employee = db.Employee.Find(id);
    db.Employee.Remove(employee);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```