# SQL Server 2008 on Delete Cascade

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

When foreign keys in a table have `ON DELETE CASCADE` set to them, does this mean that *"deletion is allowed"* or does it mean that SQL Server will actually perform all of the associated deletes when a record is deleted?

In other words, if I have a set of tables linked together with foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, do I have to go to each individual table and explicitly perform the delete function or will SQL Server do it for me?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444859/sql-on-delete-cascade-which-way-does-the-deletion-occur

Answer (score 2):

Use the ON DELETE CASCADE option to specify whether you want rows deleted in a child table when corresponding rows are deleted in the parent table. If you do not specify cascading deletes, the default behavior of the database server prevents you from deleting data in a table if other tables reference it.

Took that from IBM site. I guess it means yes! :)

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you delete a parent in a FK relationship, SQL Server will automatically delete all the children.

Comment: Which table is the parent and which is the child in this relationship?  From what I have seen so far , sql server is not automatically deleting the children.

Comment: The table with the Primary Key in the relationship is the parent.   The table with the Foreign Key that REFERENCES the other table's Primary Key is the child.

Answer (score 1):

It means that when a `Parent` row is deleted (killed), no orphan row should stay alive in the `Child` table. All childs of the parent row are killed (deleted), too. If any of these children has grandchildren (in another table through another foreign key) and there is **ON DELETE CASCADE** defined, these should be killed, too (and all descendants, as long as there is a cascade effect defined).

Took it from: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/good-explanation-of-cascade-on-delete-update-behavior