# Why is my delete operation not performing?

Tags: php, mysql

In my project, I want a delete operation for a particular id when I click on the delete button, but it isn't performing. Here's my code for displaying the table:

```
<table class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th class="first"><center>Id</center></th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th class="last">Delete</th>
      </tr>
  <?php
   include('config.php');
   $sql="select * from category_tbl";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row['cat_status'] == 0) {
  $im='<a href="category.php?false='.$row["cat_id"].'"><img src="../images/red.jpg" height="28" width="28"></a>';
    }
    else{
        $im='<a href="category.php?true='.$row["cat_id"].'"><img src="../images/green.jpg" height="30" width="30"></a>';
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['false'])) {
      $updt=mysql_query("update category_tbl set cat_status=1 where cat_id='".$_REQUEST['false']."'");
      header('location:category.php');
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['true'])) {
      $updt=mysql_query("update category_tbl set cat_status=0 where cat_id='".$_REQUEST['true']."'");
      header('location:category.php');
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $row['cat_id'];?></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $row['cat_name'];?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $im;?></td>
        <td><a href="update_cat.php?id=<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>"><img src="../images/edit.jpg" height="30" width="60" value=<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>></a></td>
        <td><a href="delete_cat.php?id=<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>"><img src="../images/delete1.jpg" height="30" width="60" value=<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  </table>
```

The edit operation is working, but delete is not.
This is my code for delete:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM category_tbl WHERE cat_id='".$id."'");
if ($sql) {
    header("location:category.php");
}   
?>
```

After execution it stays on `delete_cat.php?id=(passed id)...`.

Comment: what is your `cat_id` field in the DB? an `integer` or a `varchar`? And make this change to check for **mysql errors**: `$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM category_tbl WHERE cat_id='".$id."'") OR die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Is the row deleted in the database? And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: no,it's not deleted from database...and my cat_id is integer...

Comment: @Cliff Burton...after using die it is showing this...Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_stationery`.`product_tbl`, CONSTRAINT `product_tbl_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `category_tbl` (`cat_id`))

Comment: It means that you are trying to delete a table row which is referenced to a parent table with a `ON DELETE NO ACTION` or `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. You should revise your DB structure if you want to perform this action

Comment: Is this something that you are developing right now or is it something that you are stuck with? If the former, then you should definitely not use mysql_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to remove your foreign key from sub table or second option is you need to alter your query and set cascade like this.

> ON DELETE CASCADE

for more help visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444859/sql-on-delete-cascade-which-way-does-the-deletion-occur)