# what does on_delete=models.PROTECT and on_delete=models.CASCADE do on Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm quite familiar with Django, but recently noticed there exists a `on_delete=models.CASCADE` and `on_delete=models.PROTECT` options with the models,

- `on_delete=models.CASCADE` and `on_delete=models.PROTECT` both are doing same things.
- Or both are same (I used the only `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, when I remove the parent entry it will remove all related entries )

  I have searched for the documentation for the same but couldn't find anything more than:

> **Django 2.0**
>
> A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: the
>   class to which the model is related and the on_delete option.
>        To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use models.ForeignKey('self',
>   on_delete=models.CASCADE).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does on\_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)

Comment: [A very detailed and well explained answer to this question is at this link within stack overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)

Comment: See also: [SQL ON DELETE CASCADE, Which Way Does the Deletion Occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74781951/562769)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

- `CASCADE`
  Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the
  `SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE` and also deletes the object
  containing the `ForeignKey`.
- `PROTECT` 
  Prevent deletion of the referenced object by `raising`
  `ProtectedError`, a subclass of `django.db.IntegrityError`.

the things get deleted because once you change your model you need to do `makemigrations` and `migrate` to see the change.

Comment: Which is the better option to maintain the behavior before Django 2.0, and that won't crash the application? Thanks,

Comment: this medium post has a very clear explanation: https://medium.com/@inem.patrick/django-database-integrity-foreignkey-on-delete-option-db7d160762e4

Comment: if CASCADE "emulates" the SQL constraint of CASCADE.. what does the PROTECT do? I'm not familiar with that constraint type... and even more confused on why a migration is required when using PROTECT

Answer (score 28):

For `on_delete=models.CASCADE`:

You have 2 models i.e., **Car** and **Company**. You delete the company, you also delete the cars made by that company.

For `on_delete=models.PROTECT`:

You have 2 models. **Car** and **Company**. You delete the company, Django says, Hold up. Can't do it ... So everything remains.

Here's what you'll see.[image]

Comment: If you set `on_delete=Cascade`, and then delete Car, will it delete the company? Asking because it is not clear for me from the documentation

Comment: @Zhenia it only works in one direction: You have a Company, and you have a Car. Car has a manufacturer. Like this: `manufacturer = ForeignKey(to=Company, models.CASCADE)`. So if you delete a Company, manufacturer will become non-existent, so the car will be deleted too. But if you delete a Car, nothing happens with company: it just doesn't have any links to the car which require some resolving (like casacade deleting or setting it to null)

Comment: @Zhenia in other words, `on_delete` function is the way Django handles links that become invalid because the linked object is deleted. But if you delete the Car, it doesn't affect a company as it doesn't link to the car.